# Android: How to update build.gradle?

Tags: android

I need gradle ver 2.1.4 so I tried changing

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4'

but it didn't work. I also tried this method http://devdeeds.com/update-gradle-plugin-android-studio/    but that didn't work either.
This is the error that I am getting

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.4. Searched in
>   the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/Reimu/Downloads/android-studio-ide-145.3200535-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.4/gradle-2.1.4.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Reimu/Downloads/android-studio-ide-145.3200535-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.4/gradle-2.1.4.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.4/gradle-2.1.4.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.4/gradle-2.1.4.jar
>   Required by:
>       :MyApp:unspecified

I can't run any projects without this being updated apparently.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

The `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'` is not for Gradle itself, but the [Gradle Android build plugin](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle) that you apply with the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` or `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in your module's **build.gradle** file.

If you want to use another version of **gradle** in your project, reconfigure your **gradle wrapper**. Search for the `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your project root, and apply the correct `distributionUrl`, for example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

For the 2.14.1 version of **gradle**. This is probably what you need, because [there is no such thing as Gradle v. 2.1.4](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/). There is also [no Android Gradle plugin v. 2.1.4](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle).

And if it turns out, that you need the newest android grade build plugin, then change your class path to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta2'`. Version 2.1.3 is currently the newest stable version.

Comment: neither worked but I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1ApErUGZ_M and it somehow worked.  Thank you though!

Comment: Newest Android Gradle Plugin; https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html